# Cross browser color input

Tags: html, input, colors

I want to style html5 color input

```
<input type="color"> . . .
```

Every os opens this different. I want to style it , or can you offer me something else.

Thank you

Comment: Every OS *and every browser* will offer it differently due to their custom implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Well, since you said that we can offer something else, the company I used to work for had a lot of success with the JSColor library. http://jscolor.com. It's customizable and cross-browser.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the support matrix for that tag: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-color

As you may see you need to consider some cross-browser library if you are not limited to Chrome.